# I can't create relationships in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server

This is what I get every time I try to create a new relationship and I don't know what to do.

> The columns in table 'Cartea' do not match an existing primary key or
> UNIQUE constraint.

[image]

That's the data from the tables.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide the structure of the tables Cartea and Id_Librairie?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're adding the foreign key from the wrong table. Since you're using the wizard to create it, you should start from `Cartea` table. It should look like this:

[image: wizard configuration]

And here is the equivalent T-SQL command:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Cartea]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Cartea_Librarie] FOREIGN KEY([Id_librarie])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Librarie] ([Id_librarie])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Cartea] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Cartea_Librarie]
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be great to see the Cartea table definition. But it writes there. Is id_librarie in cartea table a primary key or unique?
Because if not, that would imply a one child many parents relationship which doesn't make much sense and is the reason for the error.

More reading here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667818/sql-server-2008-the-columns-in-table-do-not-match-an-existing-primary-key-or-un/14060227